# Is $\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}\binom{a}{i}\binom{2a-i}{a} $ even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to know if the expression
$$\sum_{i=0}^{a-1}\binom{a}{i}\binom{2a-i}{a} $$
is zero mod $2$.

I know that I have to look at binary expansion of numbers $a$, $2a$ and $2a-i$, then use the theorem that

> If $m=a_0+a_p+\cdots+a_rp^r$ and $n=b_0+b_1p+\cdots+b_rp^r$, then $$\binom{m}{n}\equiv\prod_{i=0}{r}\binom{a_i}{b_i}$$ in mod $p$

In the case $i=0$, we have $\binom{2a}{a}$ which is even.
This is because, if $a=2^{j_1}+\cdots+2^{j_k}$, then $2a=2^{j_1+1}+\cdots+2^{j_k+1}$, thus
$$\binom{2a}{a}\equiv \binom{0}{1}(\text{other binomial coefficients})=0 $$

For the rest, I have no idea.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is even. Actually, ALL terms in your sum are even!
For $i=0,\dots,a-1$,
$$\begin{align}
\binom{a}{i}\binom{2a-i}{a}&=\frac{a!}{i!(a-i)!}\cdot\frac{(2a-i)!}{a!(a-i)!}=\frac{(2(a-i))!}{(a-i)!(a-i)!}\cdot\frac{(2a-i)!}{i!(2(a-i))!}
\\
&=\binom{2(a-i)}{a-i}\binom{2a-i}{i}
=2\binom{2(a-i)-1}{a-i-1}\binom{2a-i}{i}\equiv 0\pmod 2.
\end{align}$$
Note that $\binom{a}{i}\binom{2a-i}{a}$ is $T(a,i)$ in [OEIS's sequence A104684](http://oeis.org/A104684).

Comment: Thank you in advance for the answer, specially for $T(a,i)$